# How get a emulator with real screen size in AVD

Tags: android, virtual-device-manager

I have created a virtual device to run my android application. I put 5.1 inch for screen size in **Configure Hardware Profile** . Then I changed other configurations which are suitable for the application.

When I started the AVD,it is launched properly,but its screen size is too large . i.e,  **AVD**'s screen size is larger than actual screen size .

Example :- **Samsung S6 EDGE** screen size is 5.1 inch. But in a **AVD** , it is not 5.1 inch.

Is is this a error or something wrong with my selection ?

How could I get actual screen size of a device as screen size of an AVD ?

Comment: Try it with other devices,see if the problem still persists.If does it is better to run it in genymotion or in a real device.@Barrier

Comment: @CrazyAndroid : I have done what you suggested . Do you have any ideas without this?